# How to style RadioButtonList items in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, styles

> How to set  RadioButtonList items placed front of each others in **Asp.Net**?
>   I have a RadioButtonList with 3 items

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">    
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item1</asp:ListItem>    
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item2</asp:ListItem>   
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want this:

*Item1   *Item2   *Item3

Not this:

*Item1

*Item2

*Item3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this class named one in style tag in head and add RadioButtonList tag to body tag

```
 .one {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }




<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Class="one">Item1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Class="one">Item2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Class="one">Item3</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. i thought it is not workin because VS2013 wrote Attribute 'class' is not valid attribute for 'ListItem'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Item3</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved but i can't set the style for each ListItems. How can i do?

Comment: What type of Style You want?

Comment: I want set the margin and padding for one by one of them